# Existence of groups corresponding to dimensions of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

If there are $r$ irreducible representations of a group $G$, we know that $|G| = \sum_{i=1}^{r}d_{i}^2$ and $d_i$ divides $|G|$. Suppose we have a decomposition of $N$ such that $N = \sum_{i=1}^{r}d_{i}^2$ and $d_i | N$, does that mean there will be a group corresponding to this with such irreducible representations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N = 4$ and $d_1 = 2$ then such group cannot exist since every finite group has the trivial representation.

So the answer to your question is 'no' in general.

Comment: More generally, the number of $1$'s must divide the sum of the squares.

Comment: I probably saw this kind of problem (= what kind of sequence has a corresponding group?) was open. (And it may still open. Perhaps in  R. Brauer's article "Representations of finite groups", Lectures on Modern Mathematics, vol I.)

Comment: @Orat Can you tell me the exact place where you found such a problem?

Comment: I checked in a library. The article of R. Brauer in [the book](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/25499910) mentions about similar problem (between problem 1 and 2).